# Can I use multiple keys in Berkeley DB?

Tags: perl, berkeley-db

I want to use in Berkeley DB the following Perl logic (for many millions records):

```
$hash{key1}{key2}{key3}{count1}++;
$hash{key1}{key2}{key3}{count2}++;

...

for (key1) {
   for (key2) {
     for (key3) {
        print $hash{key1}{key2}{key3}{count1}."\t".$hash{key1}{key2}{key2}{count2};
        }
     }
  }
```

Any example from multiple keys? I may of couse use "pseudo-multiple" key ( key1_key2_key3 ); but is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

Berkeley-db doesn't support multiple keys like that.  Each record can have only one key.

You can concatenate the keys to form a single key, as you stated.

You can use [MLDBM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MLDBM) to give the appearance of nested keys.  But that works by storing a serialized hash under `key1`, so it will be very inefficient if you have a lot of keys nested under the top-level key.

Or, you can give up on BDB and go with a real SQL database.  [DBD::SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aSQLite) is easy to install and includes the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database engine along with its driver.

I'd go with either concatenating the keys or a real database, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: DBM::Deep is a less-shonky alternative to MLDBM.

Answer (score 0):

As this condition,to solve the problem you can just construct a unique-key like this:

```
$seperator = "_"; #seperator depends on your data,pick one never found in your key.
$key = join $seperator , ($key1,$key2,$key3);
$hash{$key}{$count1}++;
$hash{$key}{$count2}++;

...

for (key1) {
   for (key2) {
     for (key3) {
        $un_key = join $seperator , (key1,key2,key3);
        print $hash{$un_key}{count1}."\t".$hash{$un_key}{count2};
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Berkeley database supports multiple keys, although the API for doing this is not available in all languages.  Take a look at the section "Secondary Keys" in the document "Berkeley DB Concepts"

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/gsg/JAVA/javadplconcepts.html#secondary